# When do I get my first companion?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

I know you can get a companion in Star Wars: The Old Republic, but when do you get said companion?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This varies from class to class, but you should get your first companion as part of the storyline missions in your beginner zone. You'll be in the range of level 5-10.

Comment: I'll be honest, but I suspected that having played through two classes starting areas... but it's an extremely common question in chat, so I decided to ask it anyway.

Comment: @Powerlord I figured it just had something to do with [hats](http://hatdash.com/#hats)

Comment: That's a secret to everyone (see the SWTOR hat requirement)

Comment: Oh, and accepting this answer gave me one, too.  Plus, I'm building up lots of comments!

Comment: @Powerlord Not me. I would never let such silly incentives affect my behavior.

Comment: The other thing is that I was accepted for a Gaming Grant for this particular game, so I need to ask and answer lots of questions.

Answer (score 2):

You first have to complete most of your class quest. You are most likely to get it between 7-9. If you see other people with companions at 5 or 6 that means they didn't do any other quest really. Hopes this helps guys!